# How to plot on grid with refinements?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35126402/9841338)

My data comes in the form of a (3 × N) array

```
[[x_0, ..., x_N-1],
 [y_0, ..., y_N-1],
 [z_0, ..., z_N-1]]
```

I want to plot it such that the first two lines code the X, Y position of a pixel and the third line sets the pixel's color.

However, I do not want any interpolation to take place. Rather, **the space is tiled by the fact that all points lie on a grid**, with lower divisions being refinements of the original grid. Here is some dummy data

```
[[4, 12, 24,  4, 12, 20, 28,  8, 18, 22, 28, 17, 19, 22, 17, 19],  # X
 [4,  4,  8, 12, 12, 20, 20, 24, 26, 26, 28, 29, 29, 30, 31, 31],  # Y
 [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]  # Z (color)
```

These pixels have size

```
D = [8,  8, 16,  8,  8,  8,  8, 16,  4,  4,  8,  2,  2,  4,  2,  2]
```

Illustrated here is the desired position and spatial extent for the pixels corresponding to the dummy data above.

[image]

Now, I could interpolate my data to match the finest grid points, but that will be inefficient and not very elegant. Some areas of my grid may be much more refined than others.

**Is there a way to make this kind of plot in matplotlib?**

EDIT
To clarify, refining a pixel in position (x, y) of size (d×d) gives 4 pixels in positions (x - d/4, y - d/4), (x + d/4, y - d/4), (x - d/4, y + d/4),(x + d/4, y + d/4), each of size (d/2 × d/2). Positions always refer to the center of a pixel.

Comment: if needed, you may assume that I already have a function to computes the size d of a pixel based on its position (its simply proportional to the index of its non-zero bit of largest weight)

Comment: What is `d` here?

Comment: the width of a pixel (I define it in the EDIT). e.g. in the dummy data above `d` for the (4,4) pixel is 8 because the pixel is 8 by 8 on the blue grid.

Comment: What I mean is, e.g. the first pixel is centered at (4,4), but what is it's `d` value? 16 I suppose? So do you have an array of `d` values for each pixel?

Comment: See my 1st comment, I have a function that can compute an array D of values of d given X and Y.

Comment: I am not keeping it secret, its drawn on the figure. but I'll add this explicitly to the question. The problem is I don't see how to obtain the plot in question because e.g. imshow expects a regular grid, and mesh based solutions I've found tend to interpolate between datapoints, which I do not want.

Comment: Either your formula `(x - d/4, y - d/4)` etc is wrong, or the `D` array you provided. Or maybe even x and y? So when using `(x - d/2, y - d/2)` I get at least a [pretty close result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VXtA.png). I suppose when you provide a consistent dataset I could post a solution here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had swapped two values in `D`, which explains what is shown on your figure I believe (I edited my post). I triple-checked everything else and found no inconsistency. The formula is correct but perhaps we misunderstood each other? The formula you gave are the positions of the corners of a pixel. The one I gave were the positions of the centers of the 4 pixels that are obtained by splitting a pixel. Thanks for the time you've been spending on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inbuilt function that would allow to plot an irregular grid like the one specified in the question. The solution would be to define a Collection of "pixels" with the respective edges.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

x =  np.array([4, 12, 24,  4, 12, 20, 28,  8, 18, 22, 28, 17, 19, 22, 17, 19])  # X
y =  np.array([4,  4,  8, 12, 12, 20, 20, 24, 26, 26, 28, 29, 29, 30, 31, 31])  # Y
z =  np.array([1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])  # Z (color)
D =  np.array([8,  8, 16,  8,  8,  8,  8, 16,  4,  4,  8,  2,  2,  4,  2,  2])


def irregularmesh(x, y, s, c, ax=None, **kwargs):
    xedge = np.c_[-s, s, s, -s]/2. + np.atleast_2d(x).T
    yedge = np.c_[-s, -s, s, s]/2. + np.atleast_2d(y).T
    xy = np.stack((xedge,yedge), axis=2)

    # Create collection of rectangles.
    pc = PolyCollection(xy, closed=True, **kwargs)
    pc.set_array(c)
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.add_collection(pc)
    return pc

######## Plotting ################
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pc = irregularmesh(x, y, D, z, ax=ax, linewidth=0, cmap="inferno")
fig.colorbar(pc, ax=ax)

ax.margins(0)
ax.autoscale()

for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(4))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It took me some time to understand it, but it does work like a charm!